# Apply box shadow to border in css

Tags: html, css, styles, shadow

I made this button design in Figma and would like to apply it in CSS.

[image]

If you look closely you can see that I applied a highlight with a white shadow on the border

But when I do it with the following CSS lines it just has a shadow inside and not on the border like this image shows.

[image]

```css
div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.7em;
  border-color: var(--highlight);
  box-shadow: inset 0.2em 0.2em 0.4em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), inset -2px -2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}
```

```html
<div> Sign Up </div>
```

how can I apply the highlight/shadow on the border?

Comment: inset applies the shadow inside of an element instead of outside

Comment: That doesn't look like a shadow to me, it looks like a gradient border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style> 
#example3 {
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px
}
#bg{
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center
}
</style>
```

```
<div id="bg">
<div id="example3">
  <p>A pink shadow.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have trying to create the div looks like your Figma design,
I use the combination of normal (outset) box-shadow and inset box-shadow.
The outset was used to give bright shadow and make the div looks stronger, and I saw the figma show the darker inner shadow to make the border looks a little bit 3D.

NOTE: I use border-style: ridge to make the border looks 3D as shown in Your Figma, you can make it flat by using border-style: solid
[Capture attached below

```
body{
  background-color: rgb(50, 53, 90);
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: .6rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: ridge;
  border-width: 0.2em;
  border-color: rgb(251, 55, 102);
  box-shadow:  0em 0em 1.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), inset 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}
```

[Using border-style: ridge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W5lj.png)

```
body{
  background-color: rgb(50, 53, 90);
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: .6rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.2em;
  border-color: rgb(251, 55, 102);
  box-shadow:  0em 0em 1.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), inset 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}
```

[Using border-style: solid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlxwx.png)

Sorry if this is not what you want, I hope you like my answer

Answer (score 0):

[Image showing box shadow effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzDON.jpg)>
box-shadow: 0 0 25px color-of-choice;

This will create a faint shadow all around the image or block.
Make sure the color matches with your background color.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30060346)

Comment: @Option the "link" is an image.